# Is there a way to use an if statement in excel to return a person's name if it is 2 words vs. 3 words

Tags: excel, if-statement

[image]

Formula in column B:
=LEFT(A2, FIND(" ", A2, FIND(" ", A2) + 1) - 1)

Formula in column C:
=IF(B2<>"Null",B2,A2)

I want to be able to return the 2 word name in column C and am struggling to find how. Any tips?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you could add replace the second `find(...)` by `if(iserror(find(...),"",find(...))`.  That's not the most elegant solution, and a tricky one, because it will catch all errors in the same way.  I can't really think of anything else, unless if I make things very complex with a bunch of ifs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return only the first two words:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1&"  "," ","}}}",2))-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2;" ";""))>1;LEFT(A2;(LEN(A2)-LEN(RIGHT(A2;FIND(" ";A2)))));A2)
```

I believe that this is what you're looking for. In the formula, if the number of `" "` is more than one, it only takes the first two words into account. Otherwise, it just rewrites the input.

I hope that will work!